# Erase inside a std::string by std::string_view

Tags: c++, string, c++17, string-view

I need to find and then erase a portion of a string (a substring). `string_view` seems such a good idea, but I cannot make it work with `string::erase`:

```
// guaranteed to return a view into `str`
auto gimme_gimme_gimme(const std::string& str) -> std::string_view;

auto after_midnight(std::string& str)
{
    auto man = gimme_gimme_gimme(str);

    str.erase(man); // way to hopeful, not a chance though
    str.erase(man.begin(), man.end()); // nope
    str.erase(std::distance(str.begin(), man.begin()), man.size()); // nope
    str.erase(std::distance(str.data(), man.data()), man.size()); // nope again

    // for real???
}
```

Am I overthinking this? Given a `std::string_view` into a `std::string` how to erase that part of the string? Or am I misusing `string_view`?

Comment: I wouldn't use a string_view here.  I would either return a `pair<size_t, size_t>` where `first` is the index of the substring and `second` is the length, or just modify `gimme_gimme_gimme` to actually do the erasure.

Comment: When you say "erase portion of string" what do you mean? If string is "abbabca", and string view is "ab", then what do you want erased exactly?

Comment: @eerorika a substring. In your example if I understand the view is into the first two characters of the string, erasing that gives `"ba"`

Comment: @bolov I edited my comment

Comment: @eerorika oh I see. I mean a substring of the original string. The `string_view` is a view into the original string, it does not point to another object.

Comment: @bolov Oh, I see.

Comment: So, essentially the issue is that `std::distance` does not work with mismatched iterator and const_iterator pairs (which in this case are pointers to char and const char respectively). This is indeed an inconvenience. It's fairly reasonable that it won't work with mismatched sring_view, string iterator combo.

Comment: @NathanOliver why? It's because working with `string_view` is cumbersome? I can understand that and that means the std library needs to add APIs to work with it. Or is it because `string_view` is not meant to be used this way. And in this case I would argue that the value I personally see in `span` and `string_view` is the abstraction of a "range", going away from two separate iterator parameters to specify a range. `std::pair<size_t, size_t>` can mean `(index_begin, index_end)` or `(index_begin, length)`. I liked the idea of a class that expresses this intend of a range clearly.

Comment: @eerorika I see the very fact that we need to resort to `std::distance` an inconvenience. Ideally `str.erase(man);` should work. But since the entire std is based around `(being, end)` arguments `str.erase(man.begin(), man.end());` should have worked imho.

Comment: Yeah, my reasons is just that string view isn't built for this, and as your answer shows to make it work the code gets "ewwy".

Comment: @NathanOliver so basically we still don't have a way to work elegantly with contiguous portions or arrays/strings. Or maybe the the use case I see just isn't there...

Comment: @bolov I suspect that the reason why such erase overload is not in the standard is concisely expressed in your answer: "The code is error prone". Technically, it's not any more error prone that erasing iterators, but the issue is that the precondition that iterator arguments are to the same container are conventional, while precondition that string view is to the same container is non-conventional.

Comment: @eerorika that's a good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string view could indeed be empty, or it could be a view to the outside of the container. Your suggested `erase` overload, as well as the implementation of the function in your answer relies on a pre-condition that the string view is to the same string object.

Of course, the iterator overloads are very much analogous and rely on the same pre-condition. But such pre-condition is conventional for iterators, but non-conventional for string views.

I don't think that string view is an ideal way to represent the sub range in this case. Instead, I would suggest using a relative sub range based on the indices. For example:

```
struct sub_range {
    size_t begin;
    size_t count;
    constexpr size_t past_end() noexcept {
        return begin + count;
    }
};
```

It is a matter of taste whether to use `end` (i.e. `past_end`) or `count` for the second member, and to provide the other as a function. Regardless, there should be no confusion because the member will have a name. Using count is somewhat more conventional with indices.

Another choice is whether to use signed or unsigned indices. Signed indices can be used to represent backwards ranges. `std::string` interface doesn't understand such ranges however.

Example usage:

```
auto gimme_gimme_gimme(const std::string& str) -> sub_range;

auto after_midnight(std::string& str)
{
    auto man = gimme_gimme_gimme(str);
    str.erase(man.begin, man.distance);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Am I overthinking this?

You're under thinking it, unless I'm missing something obvious. To make the code compile you need this:

```
auto gimme_gimme_gimme(const std::string& str) -> std::string_view;

auto after_midnight(std::string& str)
{
    auto man = gimme_gimme_gimme(str);

    str.erase(std::distance(std::as_const(str).data(), man.data()), man.size()); // urrr... growling in pain
}
```

But wait!! There's more! Notice I said "to make it compile". The code is error prone!! Because...

`std::string::data` cannot be nullptr but an empty `string_view` can be represented as (valid pointer inside the string + size `0`) or as (`nullptr` + size `0`). The problem arises if the `string_view::data` is `nulltpr` because of the `std::distance` used.

So you need to make sure that the `string_view` always points inside the string, even if the view is empty. Or do extra checks on the erase side.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious?